# I need to implement an API key in Kotlin (Volley)

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-volley, api-key

Ok so, this is the code I use to do an API request:

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        var url = "https://randomfox.ca/floof/"
        

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                
                binding.textAPI.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 10)}" //outputs the first 10 characters
                println(response)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                binding.textAPI.text = "That didn't work!"
            })
        
        queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Here is the question: How do I implement an API key here?

This might be a really silly question but I'm totally new to Kotlin and app development in general soooo...

Comment: Don't use android-studio tag just because you're writing code in it - instead use tag of library you're implementing (in this case: android-volley).

Answer (score 1):

you can use retrofit to make API request

and then in every endpoint method, add headers like belows.

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("search/users")
    @Headers("Authorization: token ${yourKeyHere}")
    fun getProfile(@Query("q") username: String): Call<ProfileResponse>

    @GET("users/{username}")
    @Headers("Authorization: token ${yourKeyHere}")
    fun getDetail(@Path("username") username: String): Call<DetailResponse>

    @GET("users/{username}/followers")
    @Headers("Authorization: token ${yourKeyHere}")
    fun getFollowers(@Path("username") username: String): Call<List<UserItemResponse>>

    @GET("users/{username}/following")
    @Headers("Authorization: token ${yourKeyHere}")
    fun getFollowing(@Path("username") username: String): Call<List<UserItemResponse>>
}
```

hope it's help.